# NotificationChannel added sound to my notification that didn't have sound before

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

After adding this to my code:

```
mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, importance);
notificationChannel.enableLights(false);
notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);                        
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
```

My notification that previously didn't have a sound now has a sound. On  my notification builder I've switched the priority to low because I read that could make it have a sound and now I don't really know what else to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out once the channel has been created it has the importance there forever. Deleting the channel fixed the issue.